# call a method with specific (optional) arguments

Tags: javascript, methods

I need to use a built-in Foo method which has 6 parameters (2 required, 4 optionals)

```
Param1 > Required
Param2 > Required
Param3 > Optional > Default value: False (type boolean) 
Param4 > Optional > Default value: False (type boolean)  
Param5 > Optional > Default value: 0 (type integer)
Param6 > Optional > Default value: False (type boolean)
```

I need to change Param5 only to a different value.

Is there a way to avoid using all the default parameters?

```
bar.Foo(x, y, false, false, 10, false)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is something along these lines, where I'm only using what's not default

```
bar.Foo(x, y, 10)
```

where x is Param1, y is Param2, and 10 is Param5

Comment: you can pass `undefined`, like `bar.Foo(x, y, undefined, undefined, 10, undefined)`

Comment: Consider passing an object and using destructuring instead?

Answer (score 2):

Usually when I start working with function that have too many optional params I change my approach to using an options object instead of creating more and more parameters on my function... as you felt this can get messy and quite annoying...

So for example in your case I would change it to something like this...

```js
const bar = {
  Foo: (param1, param2, options) => {
    const {param3 = false, param4 = 10, param5 = false} = options;
    
    console.log({param1, param2, param3, param4, param5});
  }
}


const x = 1; const y = 2;
bar.Foo(x, y, {param4: 10})
```